# jquery.js not working after integrate with laravel-mix

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel mix feature its working fine I am using jquery with mix feature.

When I am run `npm run dev` command my all files mix successfully and load in view successfully but javascript not working properly I got `$ not found` error.

**My mix file code below**

```
mix.js('node_modules/plugins/jQuery/jquery.min.js','public/js')
```

**My view code for load scripts below**

```
{!! Html::script(mix('js/jquery.min.js')) !!}
```

It is loading properly but not working if anybody knows any about solution send me.

Comment: How is you public folder structured after mix?

Comment: My public folder is currect and my jquery is also loaded in view but not working.                                                                                                           /var/www/html/myProject/public/jquery.js

Comment: You are saying that your jquery is in ` /var/www/html/myProject/public/jquery.js` folder. So you need to load it as `{!! url('jquery.min.js') !!}` (I do not know where `Html::script` comes from)